# How many strings can I make with all captials letters of length 4 that have exactly 2 A's and 2 B's?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, discrete-optimization

My attempt on the problem:

X X X X = 26^4 number of ways the strings can be made

A A X X = 26^2 number of strings with two A's in them

B B X X = 26^2 number of strings with two B's in them

B B A A = 1 way the string is duplicated

A A B B = 1 way the string is duplicated

Then if I do 26^4 - 26^2 - 26^2 - 1 - 1,  I should be able to find the number of strings.

I believe this is right but I'm not entirely sure. Opinions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If length $4$ and $2$ A's and $2$ B's the other letters are not relevant.

Comment: Not following.  If you require exactly two $A's$ and exactly two $B's$ then the only possibilities are $AABB,ABAB,ABBA,BAAB,BABA,BBAA$.  Or did you mean something else?

Comment: Now that I see your answers I feel a little dumb. I was overthinking this. LOL thanks your guys